# Math not working correctly in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm basically trying to work out the percentage of sales completed as per the amount bought, here's the code I'm working it out with:

```
$sold = 212;
$bought = 213;

echo round(($bought / $sold) * 100)."%";
```

Why does that echo `100%` when it's clearly not? shouldn't it be like `99.5%`?

Comment: First of all , when you want to ($bought / $sold) * 100 => 100.4 , but when ($sold/ $bought) * 100. Its true , 99.5.But you are rounding the results 

`<?php

$sold = 212;
$bought = 213;

echo (float)(($sold / $bought) * 100)."%";

?>`

Comment: Because, '213/212' = '1.00471698113208'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you are rounding the result...

Try with:

```
echo round(($bought / $sold) * 100,1)."%";
```

Comment: [PHP: round - Manual](http://us3.php.net/round)

Comment: Thank you very much, appears to have worked!

Answer (score 1):

Your rounding suffers from wrongly positioned brackets! Try `echo round(100.0*$bought/$sold,2)."%";`

Answer (score 0):

It works out to 99.53051643192488%. The round function rounds the number off to the closest whole number, in this case, 100.

See also: [PHP Floor](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) and [PHP Ceil](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php). Floor rounds down, ceil rounds up.

```
echo floor(($bought / $sold) * 100)."%";
echo ceil(($bought / $sold) * 100)."%";
```